# while installing scanity Error: spawn cmd ENOENT

Tags: node.js, npm, cmd, spawn

⠋ Waiting for browser login to complete... Press Ctrl + C to cancelnode:events:505
throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
^

Error: spawn cmd ENOENT
at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (node:internal/child_process:283:19)
at onErrorNT (node:internal/child_process:478:16)
at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:83:21)
Emitted 'error' event on ChildProcess instance at:
at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (node:internal/child_process:289:12)
at onErrorNT (node:internal/child_process:478:16)
at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:83:21) {
errno: -4058,
code: 'ENOENT',
syscall: 'spawn cmd',
path: 'cmd',
spawnargs: [
'/c',
'start',
'""',
'/b',
'https://api.sanity.io/v1/auth/login/github?type=listen^&uuid=9b8a14a23276e73608528a6408902f44^&source=cli'
]
}

Answer (score 0):

Add `C:\Windows\System32` to the PATH environment variable.